# Distribution of php's random_int() function

Tags: php, unix, random

What is the distribution of php's [random_int](http://php.net/manual/de/function.random-int.php) function?

I guess it comes down to the distribution of [getrandom(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) and `/dev/urandom`? How are they distributed?

Can `random_int` be used for a uniform distributed random number generator?

Comment: From PHP documentation: "Generates cryptographic random integers that are suitable for use where unbiased results are critical". From this I would assume that the distribution is uniform. After all, it would make no sense if `random_int` or `/dev/urandom` were not uniform, since it is arguably easier to generate random data of other distributions from a uniform one, than it is to do it the other way.

Comment: If its important to you, why don't you test it? Assuming you need a particular distribution, then this would be the first step to generating a mapping function.

Comment: @symcbean was more interested in the general concept than testing for my specific environment, as judging from my understanding the randomness can eben be hardware specific.

Answer (score 0):

From php manual for [random_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php):

> On Windows, [CryptGenRandom()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) will always be used.
>      On Linux, the [getrandom(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) syscall will be used if available.
>      On other platforms, /dev/urandom will be used.

Which means the distribution is OS dependant...
So, I think it's not so easy to answer to the original question 'What is the distribution of php's random_int function?'.. On Linux, for example, from [a discussion](https://lwn.net/Articles/606141/) about `int getrandom(void *buf, size_t buflen, unsigned int flags);`:

```
[...] The GRND_RANDOM flag bit can be used to switch to the /dev/random pool, subject to the entropy requirements of that pool [...]
```

So, based on different run-time arguments, random distribution may differ in the *same* OS...

Comment: I don't think the distribution would differ, since `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` will most likely use the same source of randomness.

Comment: well i read that part of the documentation before asking. thats why i added it probably comes down to getrandom(2) or /dev/urandom. Should've probably asked about distribution of getrandom(2) and /dev/urandom :). So the part that it's OS dependant is right. But perhabs there can be given answers about the distribution of urandom and getrandom(2)? Or can even alter different hardware the "random hardware noise" enough to alter distribution?